# what is the simple validation code for a text box to limit values and decimal places?

Tags: c#, textbox, character, ascii, decimal-point

I want to limit the values that can be entered into a text box to be;

- numbers only
- backspace allowed
- space disabled
- positive only
- three decimal places

for another text box all of above but only alow values between 0 and 1

```
char ch = e.KeyChar;
            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && PercentBar.Text.IndexOf(@"\.\d\d") != -1 
                && ch != 8 && ch != 46 && ch != 32)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
```

this is my current code, but it doesn't seem to be doing a lot

Comment: Please don't try to enforce formats on keystrokes; that causes problems with cut and paste, drag and drop, editing, ease of access, macros, and such. Only validate text fields upon submitting the form or whatever.

Comment: @DourHighArch Or when leaving focus

Comment: how would you solve the prolem? i'm a beginer all help is appreciated

Comment: I agree with @DourHighArch but would add that you can add some sort of "live" validation that runs anytime the contents of the text box changes and provides visual feedback (red highlight or background, etc.) if validation fails.  This way all you have to do is parse the value an int and you can run your tests directly on that value; much easier than trying to figure out all of the ways users could (intentionally or unintentionally) get around your current approach.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: Check out the [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.7.2) events in Microsoft's documentation.  The examples there should help you get what you want.

Comment: Which UI technology: Windows Forms, [WPF](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)?